# if else shorthand crashes on setting bool in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, if-statement, swift2, shorthand

I literally have 4 line of code.

```
var bool = true

let textField1 = UITextField()

let textField2 = UITextField()

bool ? textField1.enabled = false : textField2.enabled = false
```

The above code fails with following error.

[image]

if I write the following way the code works

```
if bool {

   textField1.enabled = false
}
else {

   textfield2.enabled = false
}
```

If I write the following way then short hand of if else works

```
bool ? print("It's True") : print("It's False")
```

Why is my code failing?

Comment: You should use the if-else statement instead of the ternary operator, as the code becomes more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that Swift is not expecting you to behave like this. Thus, it sees the second term in the ternary as `textField2.enabled`, which is a Bool. But the first term, `textField1.enabled = false`, is *not* a Bool; it is a Void.

(That is why your `print` example works; *both* terms are Voids.)

As i_am_jorf says, you can work around this by disambiguating with parentheses.

However, it would be better not to do this at all. Your code is not very Swifty. You should not be using the ternary operator for side effects in this way. You should be using it for the *result* of each of its terms. This is much cleaner and even shorter:

```
(bool ? textField1 : textField2).enabled = false
```

Comment: In the same way, your `print` example would be better written `print(\(bool ? "It's true" : "It's false"))`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
bool ? (textField1.enabled = false) : (textField2.enabled = false)
```

Note that the ternary operator is not an "if-else shorthand".  It is defined as:

> The ternary conditional operator evaluates to one of two given values based on the value of a condition. It has the following form:
>
> condition ? expression used if true : expression used if false
>
> If the condition evaluates to true, the conditional operator evaluates the first expression and returns its value. Otherwise, it evaluates the second expression and returns its value. The unused expression is not evaluated.

It's purpose is to assign a value based on a condition, not to allow flow control.

Comment: Very nice. Actually `bool ? textField1.isEnabled = false : (textField2.isEnabled = false)` will do.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is due to how swift does operator precedence evaluation?

Comment: @Or it's just plain not expecting such a perverse line of code. :)